# Way to fetch rown in batch from mysql using hibernate from mentioned row onward

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have one query in service class
  PageRequest page = new PageRequest(pageNo,batchSize , new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "Id")));
             Page pPage = this.pRepository.findByStatusAndParentPId( Status.PENDING, -1, page);

where **batchSize=500**

In repository we have following code:

```
@Query("select p from Part p where p.succeedOn IS NOT  NULL and p.Status=? and p.parentId=?")
    Page<Payment> findByStatusAndParentId( String status, Integer parentId, Pageable p);
```

Now flow is like this, i want to fetch 500 rows everytime whose status is pending and then i need to process it and need to change the status to success. So using Pageable is giving me wrong result because , suppose it fetch first 500 rows whose status is pending , it processed it and changed the status to success, now it will again make sql query and will fetch row from 501 to 1000 , but actually row 1 to 500 also have status pending as older processed rows status changed to success, so they will not be covered in sql query.

Now to solve this i want to do pagenation with from last row of last  fetched Id , say last time it fetched from 100 to 600, then i want to give 601 as argument and want to fetch all rows onward..... hopefully i am able to explain my answer. Limit in query do not work in JPA.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just keep fetching page 1. Assuming each batch is processed in its own transaction, then by the time you process the second batch, page 1 should give you the next 500 un-processed rows

Comment: Is there is any other way to fetch 500 rows at a time apart from pageRequest? Limit will not work